# libcurl - прогресс получения данных с сервера

Tags: c, curl

Подскажите пожалуйста, а чем принципиально отличаются эти две опции и их callback`и:

> CURLOPT_WRITEDATA/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION

и

> CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION

Вроде бы обоих случая callback функция вызывается при готовности принять данные и в обоих случаях в колбеки приходит информация о кол-ве принятых байт.

Теоретически условный прогресс-бар можно построить на обоих функциях получается ?

Comment: Если нужен прогресс, то используйте функцию [CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION - progress meter callback](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html). Это её прямое назначение.